# How can I force Dropbox to upload even if the charge is low?

Tags: dropbox

The battery percentage on my tablet has reached 30%, which is still reporting as about 11 hours left before it goes flat. However, my Dropbox app has stopped uploading files reporting:

> Camera Upload (x left): Low battery, charge to resume

I'm not anywhere near anything I can use to start it but I want it to continue uploading screenshots I take in the mean time.

How can I force Dropbox to upload even if the charge is low?

Comment: Haven't got anything with a low enough battery around to test, but I'm pretty sure that it still allows you to manually upload files if you open the app and upload the pictures yourself.

Comment: I don't want to do it manually though! There definitely doesn't seem to be a setting to override the behaviour that I can kind though

Comment: Sounds like a feature request that you should make of the Dropbox folks.

Comment: It is advisable we address our comments on the matter (and/or follow up its updates) on [this Dropbox forum post](https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/communities/public/questions/203817285-Android-Camera-upload-charge-to-resume-). The more followers/answers, the better are the chances the issue will be resolved.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Currently the official Dropbox app doesn't support automatic camera upload if you have charge less than 30%. You can do it manually though or through a browser.

Only 3rd party apps like [DropSync](http://www.appbrain.com/app/dropsync-%28dropbox-autosync%29/com.ttxapps.dropsync) can upload when it is at low charge.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know of a way to cause the DropBox app to do it, but if you use DropSync (an third-party app that syncs Android<->DropBox), you can control the sync vs. battery behavior.

Answer (score 4):

Go to apps and start dropbox. From the hamburg menu select settings (the wheel icon). Scrolldown until you see "upload when". Select and slide to  when the charge is greater than ... whatever value, 5%. That should do.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted - perhaps because it answers an older question with details from a newer version.  Given the other answers, this was probably not an option in 2013, but it is with the version in 2017.   +1 this helped me a lot, thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Plug it into charge...it will upload straight away. Not always feasible I know but at least you don't actually have to wait for the battery charge to be higher...it does go ahead and upload straight away.

Answer (score 1):

There is a setting now, but the minimum charge is 10%. Even if plugged in, the dropbox app won't auto-upload unless at least 10% (30% by default).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there is a setting in the Android app -> When to Upload. Set it to whatever you want.